# ajax call sending null value to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

my model:

```
    public class Hello
{
    public List<string> name;
    public List<string> phone;
    public List<string> contact;

}
```

my controller code is

```
  public ActionResult Home(Hello obj) // obj is coming out to be null
    {

    }
```

my script is

```
     var names =[];
     var phones =[];
     var contacts = [];

     // some code to fill the arrays 

    var obj = [{
            name: names,
            phone: phones,
            contact: contacts,
          }];
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: 'Home',
            data: { obj:obj },
            success: function (data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                window.location = 'Download?fileGuid=' + response.FileGuid
                                  + '&filename=' + response.FileName;
            }
        })
```

i can see in the debugger that data is stored in the arrays but when i am sending data to controller the obj is null can someone suggests where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You have object in code behind so do not pass array of Hello object.

And also use POST request because GET request have not message body.

Please use below

```
var obj = {
            name: ['1', '2', '3'],
            phone: ['234324', '34343243', '3434234234'],
            contact: ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
        };
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'Home',
            data:JSON.stringify({ obj: obj }),
            success: function (data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
               // window.location = 'Download?fileGuid=' + response.FileGuid
                                  + '&filename=' + response.FileName;
            }
        })


public class Hello
{
    public List<string> name { get; set; }
    public List<string> phone { get; set; }
    public List<string> contact { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: the value of object is till coming to be null

Comment: Can you please paste your code here so i can give you better solution

Answer (score 0):

Actually i solved the problem , i had to set

traditional:true,

in my ajax call